# How to load database into helper and display in view with specific column

Tags: codeigniter

### footer_helper

```
<?php

function get_gadget_footer() {

//the database functions can not be called from within the helper
//so we have to explicitly load the functions we need in to an object
//that I will call ci. then we use that to access the regular stuff.
$ci=& get_instance();
$ci->load->database();

//select the required fields from the database
//$ci->db->select('name, type, setting');

//tell the db class the criteria
$ci->db->where('display', 'Footer');

//supply the table name and get the data
$query = $ci->db->get('gadgets');

foreach($query->result() as $row):


    $type['name'] = $row->name;
    $type['type'] = $row->type;
    var_dump($type);
endforeach;


return $type;

}
```

hi this is my helper page. var_dump($type) is returning me required result in form of array as:

### var_dump($type)

```
 array (size=2)
 'name' => string 'Quick Links' (length=11)
 'type' => string '<a href='www.facebook.com'>Facebook</a><br>
 <a href='#'>Twitter</a><br>
 <a href='#'>Salyani</a><br>
 <a href='#'>B&W</a><br>' (length=123)

 array (size=2)
 'name' => string 'Social Network' (length=14)
 'type' => string '<a href='#'>Facebook</a><br>
 <a href='#'>Facebook</a><br>
 <a href='#'>Facebook</a><br>
 <a href='#'>Facebook</a><br>' (length=115)
```

Now in my view page. I want display specific record in div. Like  record of name
 record of type .

Since now i had done following:

### view

```
 <?php
 $this->load->helper('footer_helper'); 
 $name = get_gadget_footer();
 ?>
 <div id="footer">
 <div id="footer_gadget_collection">


  <?php

  foreach ($name as $dat){ 

  ?>

  <?php

  ?>
    <div id="footer_subgadget">
    <div id='title'><?php echo $dat['name']; ?></div>
    <div id='description'><?php $dat['type']; ?> </div>
     </div>
   <?php

  }
  ?>
```

But, its giving me error. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your helper you are restting the name/type of the array, not building it.
It should be something like;

```
<?php
//supply the table name and get the data
$query = $ci->db->get('gadgets');
$type = array();
foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
    $type[] = array('name' => $row->name, 'type' => $row->type);
}

return $type;
```